# Declaring libraries as constants

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, constants

In NodeJS world we require modules using `require` function:

```
var foo = require ("foo");
```

In JavaScript (also in NodeJS) we have `const` keyword that creates a constant:

> ### [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)
>
> Creates a constant that can be global or local to the function in which it is declared. Constants follow the same scope rules as variables.

Example:

```
$ node
> const a = 10
undefined
> a
10
> a = 7
7
> a
10
```

My question is: would it be good to require libraries as constans?

Example:

```
const foo = require ("foo")
    , http = require ("http")
    ;

/* do something with foo and http */
```

Are there any bad/good effects using `const` instead of `var` when requiring libraries?

Comment: +1 because I didn't know a `const` keyword had been added to javascript.

Comment: @JamesDuffy: That's hardly a good reason to upvote this question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up "When should I vote up? Whenever you encounter a question, answer or comment that you feel is especially useful, vote it up!" The question was useful to me because I learned something.

Comment: @JamesDuffy I agree. I vote up the questions that contains new things for me as well. Thank you for the up vote. :-)

Comment: @JamesDuffy: It was useful for helping me to procrastinate for a few minutes, but that's _not_ the intent of that passage!! I think that's clear. Otherwise you might as well recruit everyone you know who has never programmed and therefore never heard of JavaScript, get them to upvote this question because they learnt "something", then claim you are acting in the spirit of this community. What nonsense.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit if i could down vote your comment i would. voting is at the discretion of the user. get over it.

Comment: @unsynchronized: Doesn't mean I have to like or agree with the stated reasons.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit fair enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that it became a common practice to use `const` over `var` for dependencies. At least in the Node.js source code this is happening:

- [`http.js`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/3727ae0d7dc940ee3b2bc238fc80cd3605954715/lib/http.js)

  [image]

So, I guess it's a good practice. I started to use it as well in [my modules](https://github.com/IonicaBizau).

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS hasn't any optimisations for library that requires as const - `require` is a simple non native function, which nothing is known about the type of the variable to which is assigned. There is source code of `require`:

```
Module.prototype.require = function(path) {
  assert(util.isString(path), 'path must be a string');
  assert(path, 'missing path');
  return Module._load(path, this);
};

Module._load = function(request, parent, isMain) {
  if (parent) {
    debug('Module._load REQUEST  ' + (request) + ' parent: ' + parent.id);
  }

  var filename = Module._resolveFilename(request, parent);

  var cachedModule = Module._cache[filename];
  if (cachedModule) {
    return cachedModule.exports;
  }

  if (NativeModule.exists(filename)) {
    // REPL is a special case, because it needs the real require.
    if (filename == 'repl') {
      var replModule = new Module('repl');
      replModule._compile(NativeModule.getSource('repl'), 'repl.js');
      NativeModule._cache.repl = replModule;
      return replModule.exports;
    }

    debug('load native module ' + request);
    return NativeModule.require(filename);
  }

  var module = new Module(filename, parent);

  if (isMain) {
    process.mainModule = module;
    module.id = '.';
  }

  Module._cache[filename] = module;

  var hadException = true;

  try {
    module.load(filename);
    hadException = false;
  } finally {
    if (hadException) {
      delete Module._cache[filename];
    }
  }

  return module.exports;
};
```

For more time library is an object (I think you don't have library like this `module.exports = 10`).

You can change all fields of object also if it is declared as const (If you want to get realy const object use `Object.freeze(someObject)`).

For conclusion: the effect is the same as for a common variable.
[Link](http://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/deps/v8/src/parser.cc#L1975) to V8 Variable Declaration Function used in NodeJS

Comment: Can you provide official references to support this answer?

Comment: "*the effect is the same as for a common variable*" - no, because you cannot overwerite the variable, which would allow for some static optimisations. The question is not about `require()` and what it returns, but about `const`.

Comment: *NodeJS hasn't any optimisations for library that requires as const* -  can you proof this? Then what's the purpose of `const`?

Comment: @IonicăBizău: Just because NodeJS isn't designed to make use of `const`'s advantages doesn't mean there aren't any.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That's my question: what are the good/bad effects when using `const myLib = require ("foo");`?

Comment: @IonicăBizău: you can rephrase your question as "what are the good/bad effects when using ```const myLib = {a:1}```?"

Comment: @3y3: Would that make a difference?

Comment: @Bergi: for v8 preparser ```const a = 1``` and ```const a = {b:2}``` are equals. In this situation v8 does  not optimises inner structure of variable, only pointer to it. For proof I need to post there sources of v8...

Comment: @3y3: Linking them should be enough, thanks. So you say that a `const` statement with a literal is parsed differently from a `const` statement with a function call?

Comment: @Bergi: No, vise versa I say that all ```const``` statements are parsed identically.
[Link](http://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/deps/v8/src/parser.cc#L1975) to V8 Variable Declaration Function used in NodeJS